# Find $E(XY\vert Z=1)$ if $X, Y, Z$ are three independent random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation, independence

Suppose that $X, Y, Z$ are three independent random variables where normal distributed with mean $1$ and variance $1$. Find $E(XY\vert Z=1)$.

I have tried as below.

$E(XY\vert Z=1)=E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=1\cdot 1=1.$

Is that correct answer?

I know if $X, Y, Z$ are three independent random variables then $E(X|Y)=E(X)$, $E(X|Z)=E(X)$, $E(Y|Z)=E(Y)$, etc.

But now I'm not sure if $X, Y, Z$ are three independent random variables then $E(XY\vert Z)=E(XY)$. Is this correct or incorrect?

Comment: It is correct. Rest assured.

Comment: $Z=1$ is a null event, so there isn't a well-defined conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(\cdot\mid Z=1)$ and hence $\mathbb{E}(\cdot\mid Z=1)$ is also not well-defined.

Comment: @user10354138  $Z$ is independent from $X$ and $Y$, so $\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y\mid Z=z)$ is quite well defined; it is $\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp No.  Conditioning on a null event is not a regular conditional probability full-stop.  Any probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on $(X,Y)$ would satisfy the defining property $\mathbb{Q}(E_1)\mathbb{P}(Z=z)=\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in E_1, Z=z)$ as both sides are $0$.